# What is a direct method for finding the supremum of the following inductively defined sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

The sequence is $z_1=1, z_{n+1}=\sqrt{2z_n}$. If $\epsilon>0$ is given, we must find $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $2-\epsilon<2^{1-2^{1-m}}$. But I'm not sure how to find a suitable $m$. I've tried taking a natural log, but that didn't appear to simplify things. I've attached an image[image: Sup] of the work I've done so far.

Comment: $2-\epsilon<2^{1-2^{1-m}}$ is equivalent to $1- 2^{-2^{1-m}}<\epsilon/2,$ which holds for $m$ large enough since $2^{-2^{-\infty}}=2^0=1.$

Comment: Ok, that makes sense! Thank you, Anne!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually find a suitable $m$, require $2 - \epsilon < 2^{1-2^{1-m}}$, so $1 - \frac{1}{2}\epsilon <2^{-2^{1-m}}=4^{-2^{-m}}$. Now you can take $\log$ of both sides twice: $-\ln(1 - \frac{1}{2}\epsilon) >2^{-m}\ln4$, then $-\ln\Big(-\dfrac{\ln(1 - \frac{1}{2}\epsilon)}{\ln4}\Big) <m\ln2$. If you want to tidy this up, $-\ln(1 - \frac{1}{2}\epsilon)>\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$, so the requirement is $-\ln\Big(\dfrac{\epsilon}{2\ln4}\Big) <m\ln2$. Also $-\ln\Big(\dfrac{\epsilon}{2\ln4}\Big) <-\ln\Big(\dfrac{\epsilon}{4}\Big)$, so $m>-\log_2\Big(\dfrac{\epsilon}{4}\Big)=2-\log_2 \epsilon$ will do.

A direct method for getting this is to realise that, because $2 < e$, you have $2^{-x} > 1-x$ (for $x>0$), so you could solve  $2^{- \frac{1}{2}\epsilon} <2^{-2^{1-m}}$.

Comment: Since the natural log is not defined for nonpositive numbers and $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily large, is the expression $\ln{\left(1-\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)}$ valid?

Comment: We are only interested in small $\epsilon$ for the limit, so there's no harm in requiring $\epsilon <1$, say.

Comment: I see. Thanks, mcd!